# unexpected token export in electron-react js

Tags: reactjs, electron

I'm usimg electron-react biolerplate.electron's main.js file placed in public folder.I want to add another electron file to common constants,functions.when I try to use that file it throws above error.
I want to keep main.js short .that's why I'm using another file

/public/renderer/command-executor.js

```
export const  executeCommandWithOutput=(command)=>{
    const { exec } = require('child_process');
    console.log(command);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      console.log('inside promise');
        exec(command, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
          console.log('inside execsync');
            if (err) {
              console.log(err);

                resolve(err);
            } else if (stderr) {
              console.log(stderr)

                resolve(stderr);
            } else {
                resolve(stdout);
            }
        });
    });
  }
```

public/main.js

```
const commandExecutor=require('./renderer/command-executor');
electron.ipcMain.on('launch-App',async(event,args)=>{
     commandExecutor.executeCommandWithOutput(`powershell -Command "& {Start-Process -Verb runas '${playLink}'}"`);

});
```

Comment: I don't see `export` anywhere

Comment: Your `require` statement is importing a file with a different name. Your function is created in `execute-command.js` whereas you're actually importing `./renderer/command-executor`. Unless I'm missing something here

Comment: @nopassport1 sorry its by mistake typed wrong file-name here

Comment: Are you using `babel`?

Comment: Yes I added .babelrc in root folder .but error retains

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207163/discussion-between-nopassport1-and-krazy).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you're trying to mix the ES5 `require` statement with the ES6 syntax for `export`. The two are incompatible. You either have to use one or the other.

Assuming your ES6 implementation with `babel` works fine, you should use the `import` statement like this:

```
// exporting like you are at the moment (called a named export):
export const executeCommandWithOutput = (command) =>{
    ...
}

// importing like so:
import { executeCommandWithOutput } from './renderer/command-executor';
```

But if you're using `require` in `public/main.js`, your `export` statement should look something like this:

```
exports.executeCommandWithOutput = executeCommandWithOutput
```

and your `require` will remain the same.

Here's an article to help you get a better understanding of what's happening, how the `export` functionality works in ES5 and what you can achieve with it: 
https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/

Likewise with the ES6 syntax: 
https://alligator.io/js/modules-es6/